# TimeStamp to Words Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i have a standard rails timestamp which i want to convert in words, something like :

```
Tomorrow at 13:51
Today at 20:21
On 31/12 at 10:12
```

You get the idea. Is there a method that does this and if not, what should i utilize to create it ? Can i use strftime for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe jQuery timeago plugin will help you http://timeago.yarp.com/

**EDIT**:
You can also use [Chronic](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic).

Comment: It would i guess, but this is a ruby on rails question :P

Comment: So it's about webpage, and on webpge you can use JS.

Comment: no it's about rails, and on rails you use ruby. If it was about javascript i would use the tag javascript or jquery, the question is not about the presentation part of the web application. And Chronic seems to be doing the opposite thing from what i want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it gives you exactly what you are looking for, but distance_of_time_in_words_to_now gives relative time like "about 1 hour", "Less than 1 month" etc.

If you are just looking to put a timestamp into plain language, then I don't know of anything specifically that does that.  You could easily create your own using strftime, just make special cases for timestamps that occur today or tomorrow.

Comment: yeah, i know of that function, but it's not what i want :/